# sum over matrix entries in sympy 1.0 with python 3.5

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I just discovered Sympy so I'm still not quite sure how to best work with it. 
I have an equation

[image]

with X a 20x5 Matrix, Y a 20x1 Matrix/Vektor and  beta  a 5x1 Matrix/Vektor

However the notation I know only allows me to use the i as a variable, not as a position in a Matrix. Code:

```
 from sympy import exp, init_printing, sqrt, sin, tan, cos, diff, Sum, Matrix, log, symbols, MatrixSymbol
 init_printing()
 X = MatrixSymbol('X',20,5)
 Y = MatrixSymbol('Y',20,1)
 beta = MatrixSymbol('beta',5,1)
 expr = Sum((Y[i]*exp((Matrix(X[i,:])*Matrix(beta))[0,0])),(i,1,20))
```

This throws the following Error:

```
 IndexError: Single index only supported for non-symbolic indices.
```

Googling it didn't really get me so far, as google always seems to want to talk about numpy instead of sympy. 
Also, I'm guessing this is all pretty basic, so pls pls share your wisdom ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IndexedBase`:

```
In [1]: X = IndexedBase("X")

In [2]: Y = IndexedBase("Y")

In [4]: beta = IndexedBase("beta")

In [5]: expr = Sum(Y[i]*exp(Sum(X[i, j]*beta[j], (j, 1, 5))), (i, 1, 20))

In [7]: pprint(expr)
  20                                 
_____                                
\    `                               
 \        5                          
  \      __                          
   \     \ `                         
    )     )   beta[j]*X[i, j]        
   /     /_,                         
  /     j = 1                        
 /     e                     *Y[i]
/____,                               
i = 1
```

Also take care that SymPy interprets functions mathematically. That is, the exponential of a matrix is not the exponential of its components, rather it is the matrix to which to Taylor expansion of the exponential converges. It only makes sense for square matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. In my case, its the exponential of a sum, because I multiply one line of X with the vector beta. In my forumla there is a little [0,0] missing, which I fixed, that I have in my original code.

Comment: also thanks for the "pprint" command. Makes it easier to post in the future :)

Comment: Another little problem that I found when trying to evaluate the Expression: Sympy's lambdify seems to have a problems with the IndexedBase problems. Can you recommend a workaround, or an alternative to lambdify?

Comment: It looks like a missing feature. A workaround: expr.doit() to expand the summations, then replace each instance of indexed symbols with a non-indexed symbol. You can generate lots of symbols with symarray( ).